# How to Implement dependency property on Textbox that allows numeric or alphanumeric values

Tags: wpf, textbox, dependency-properties

I am using a textbox in a WPFApplication and I want to implement a dependency property that will decide whether textbox allow input as numeric or alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are at least three ways to do this.
1) derive a sub-class, adding your dependency property
2) create an attached property
3) create and attach a behavior (using the expression SDK)